# clipboard.writeText() on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, event-handling, clipboard

I found a few entries about navigator.clipboard.writeText() but my specific question does not seem to be answered.

I call this function from some "onclick" event:

```
async function copyClipboard(copyText) {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
    return true;
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
<button onclick="copyClipboard('hi');" onpointerdown="copyClipboard('hi2');">
```

I call both because the desktop browsers seem to not execute **onpointerdown** events(?).

It works on all Desktop browsers I tried and also on Mobile Chrome. But it does not work on Opera Mobile (V75.3 on Android) and there are strange notes on [caniuse.com for iOS and Safari](https://caniuse.com/?search=writetext).

For Opera Mobile, due to caniuse.com, it should work since version 73. But it does not?

For Safari, note 1 says: *"Must be called within user gesture event handlers such as pointerdown or pointerup."*. I call my function in both **onpointerdown** event together with **onclick**, but with no effect.

Note 2 is even more disturbing to me :-(

What am I doing wrong?